# PCRE pattern to detect nested matches

Tags: php, regex, recursion, pcre

I use the following pattern to match and replace a simple IF-ELSE-ENDIF block using `preg_replace_callback`:

```
##IF (.*?)##(.*?)(?:##ELSE##(.*?))?##ENDIF##
```

The following two examples are matched and replaced correctly

```
1. ##IF x()## foo ##ENDIF##

Result:

Group 1: `x()`
Group 2: ` foo `

2. ##IF y()## foo ##ELSE## bar ##ENDIF##

Result:

Group 1: `y()`
Group 2: ` foo `
Group 3: ` bar `
```

Now I want to enhance this functionality to allow nested IF-ELSE blocks, e.g.

```
##IF g()## pre-outer-if ##IF h()## inner-if ##ENDIF## post-outer-if ##ELSE## outer-else ##ENDIF##
```

Here is [a demo](https://regex101.com/r/gw84YU/2) on regex101.com.

I played around to enhance the pattern with the recursion operator and positive lookaheads but I did not succeed. The goal is to match and replace related IF-ELSE-ENDIF blocks to allow a user to define conditional textblocks.

If possible, I want to avoid writing a language parser for this enhancement.

Thanks a lot for any suggestion!

Comment: What exactly are you doing with the matches? Please share the method with `preg_replace_callback`.

Comment: @Wiktor: The blocks are part of a bigger text and allows the users of the system to create dynamic text modules based on those conditions. The whole condition is replaced by either the ##IF## or the ##ELSE## part. The functions x(), y() or g() are just examples for a set of user defined functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
##IF (?>(.*?)##)((?>(?0)|.)*?)(?:##ELSE##((?>(?0)|.)*?))?##ENDIF##
```

It will find a outer if-block groups.

Comment: Deleted my last comment because it was wrong. This regex seems to work fine. I use it inside a loop until no more ##IF## statements are found. Could you explain why the first atomic group `(?>(.*?)##)` is necessary?

Comment: It effectively reduce backtracking in no-match case (for example, ``##IF`` witout ``##ENDIF##``). If no-matches can't occur then atomic group can be omitted.